# What is a constant like UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey for additional Japanese keyboard panel in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, textview

What is a constant like UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey for additional Japanese keyboard panel in iphone/ipad?

```
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant is the same - `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. But `- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification` event rises two times.